# Core Data comparisons within aggregate functions

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsfetchrequest, nsexpression

Core Data entity that has two properties on it: `startDay` and `startDateTime`. Both properties are NSDate objects. `startDay` has its time components set to midnight, and `startDateTime` designates a date with a time. Both “calendar days” within `startDay` and `startDateTime` are the same.

Here are some objects

```
(
    {
        startDateTime = "2014-05-27 08:00:00 +0000";
        startDay = "2014-05-27 00:00:00 +0000";
    },
    {
        startDateTime = "2014-05-27 13:00:00 +0000";
        startDay = "2014-05-28 00:00:00 +0000";
    }
)
```

Need to get objects grouped by `startDay`. Need to know if there is event in the "morning" or "afternoon".

Here's how to get results grouped by `startDay` and have earliest and latest daily events reported.

```
- (void)fetchEventDays
{
    NSExpression *startDateTimeExpression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"startDateTime"];
    NSExpression *minStartDateTime = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"min:" arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:startDateTimeExpression]];
    NSExpression *maxStartDateTime = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"max:" arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:startDateTimeExpression]];

    NSExpressionDescription *minStartDateTimeExpression = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
    minStartDateTimeExpression.name = @"minEventStartTime";
    minStartDateTimeExpression.expression = minStartDateTime;
    minStartDateTimeExpression.expressionResultType = NSDateAttributeType;

    NSExpressionDescription *maxStartDateTimeExpression = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
    maxStartDateTimeExpression.name = @"maxEventStartTime";
    maxStartDateTimeExpression.expression = maxStartDateTime;
    maxStartDateTimeExpression.expressionResultType = NSDateAttributeType;

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [RKObjectManager sharedManager].managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext;
    NSEntityDescription* entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"NIModelScheduleData" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSAttributeDescription* startDayDesc = [entity.attributesByName objectForKey:@"startDay"];

    NSFetchRequest* fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    fetch.entity = entity;
    fetch.propertiesToFetch = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:startDayDesc, minStartDateTimeExpression, maxStartDateTimeExpression, nil];
    fetch.propertiesToGroupBy = [NSArray arrayWithObject:startDayDesc];
    fetch.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];

    NSLog(@"%@", results);
}
```

That code is returning

```
(
    {
        maxEventStartTime = "2014-05-27 13:00:00 +0000";
        minEventStartTime = "2014-05-27 08:00:00 +0000";
        startDay = "2014-05-27 00:00:00 +0000";
    },
    {
        maxEventStartTime = "2014-05-28 10:00:00 +0000";
        minEventStartTime = "2014-05-28 09:00:00 +0000";
        startDay = "2014-05-28 00:00:00 +0000";
    }
)
```

It'd be way cooler if it looked like this

```
(
    {
        eveningEvent = YES;
        morningEvent = YES;
        startDay = "2014-05-27 00:00:00 +0000";
    },
    {
        eveningEvent = NO;
        morningEvent = YES;
        startDay = "2014-05-28 00:00:00 +0000";
    }
)
```

How can I modify my fetch request to get a date comparison into my `NSExpression` (or `NSExpressionDescription`?), so that Core Data checks if `min/maxEventStartTime` are before/after noon, and returns a BOOL instead of the actual `NSDate` object.